# XML child node delete without nested nodes

Tags: xml, nested

I have XML data like that

```
<Export>
    <Customer>
        <Data>
            <First_name>ABC</First_name>
            <Last_name>DEF</Last_name>
            <Addresses>
                <Address>
                    <Country>A</Country>
                    <City>B</City>
                    <Street>C</Street>
                </Address>
                <Address>
                    <Country>AA</Country>
                    <City>BB</City>
                    <Street>CC</Street>
                </Address>
            </Addresses>
        </Data>
        <Data>
            ...
        </Data> 
    </Customer>
</Export>
```

and want get XML like this using sql properties for XML types

```
<Data>
    <First_name>ABC</First_name>
    <Last_name>DEF</Last_name>
    <Address>
        <Country>A</Country>
        <City>B</City>
        <Street>C</Street>
    </Address>
    <Address>
        <Country>AA</Country>
        <City>BB</City>
        <Street>CC</Street>
    </Address>
</Data>
<Data>
    ...
</Data>
```

I used sql *.modify('delete ...) for deleting root nodes, but can't delete Addresses nodes without nested nodes(((((

Comment: Can you specify what database server you are using to manipulate XML?

Comment: I use SQL server 2014